# How to increment counter value inside an onClick event?

Tags: javascript, counter, google-app-maker

I'm quite new to Google App Maker and programming in general, I'm making an app where when a "+" button is clicked (onClick event) fields are added (kinda like a new row in a table with every click). I'm trying to make a counter to keep track of how many "rows" are being created. The thing is that since in App Maker all the code apparently has to be made inside the onClick event, i can't set a global variable and every time the button is clicked the counter restarts, therefore always being 1.

I tried with localStorage but i don't exactly know how to make it work, since it still will always save the same value. How can i fix this?

```
  var count = 0;
  count = count +1;
  localStorage.setItem('counter', JSON.stringify(parseFloat(count)));

  textArea.className = 'app-TextArea';
  textArea.style.margin = '8px';
  textArea.setAttribute("placeholder", "Follow up # " + localStorage.getItem('counter');

  widget.root.descendants.Panel1.getElement().appendChild(textArea);
```

Comment: If this is an onClick event can you post the surrounding code please.

Comment: That's the thing, in App Maker it doesn't seem like i can add surrounding code. It just gives the option to add an onClick event and add the code there, hence i cant initialize "count" outside the onClick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get data from `localStorage` first, then increment it and finally set the new value the `localStorage`.

```
var count = parseInt(localStorage('counter')) || 0; // Get value from localStorage 
count = count + 1;
localStorage.setItem('counter', count); // Set new value to localStorage

textArea.className = 'app-TextArea';
textArea.style.margin = '8px';
textArea.setAttribute("placeholder", "Follow up # " + count); // Use new value

widget.root.descendants.Panel1.getElement().appendChild(textArea);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the page **[custom properties](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/binding#custom_properties)**.

So in the the page, you can add a **Number** custom property and name it *counter*.
Then your code should look like this:

```
  var count = widget.root.properties.counter || 0;
  count += 1;
  widget.root.properties.counter = count;

  textArea.className = 'app-TextArea';
  textArea.style.margin = '8px';
  textArea.setAttribute("placeholder", "Follow up # " + count);

  widget.root.descendants.Panel1.getElement().appendChild(textArea);
```